# Least Squares Method for Continuous Function?

Tags: optimization, least-squares, estimation

I would like to find the best linear approximation for the function ($x\in \mathbb{R}$) $$f(x)=x^{-4}$$
in the range $$x\in [x_1, x_2]$$
The motivation for this is that exponential functions, as well as logarithmic functions and others, all asymptote to approach $0$ when $x$ is large, the change of slope at $x$ values away from $x=0$ is also not significant. Therefore the behavior of the function at large $x$ should be well approximated by a linear function.

My idea is to find $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ for
$$g(x)=\alpha x+\beta$$
such that
$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} [f(x)-g(x)]^2 \,dx$$
is minimized.

Is my thought correct? How could I continue?

Comment: Looks like a good start.  So now you have a function of two variables $(\alpha, \beta)$ that you need to minimize, and standard techniques apply.

Comment: If you want something quick, the tangent line to the midpoint of the interval is probably a decent guess (maybe with some restrictions on the interval).  Of course, this won't usually give you the best approximation in the sense you want.

Comment: Calculate the integral to give you a function of two variables. Put the partial derivatives with respect to $\alpha$ and $\beta$ equal to zero and solve for the two variables.

Comment: @lulu The midpoint tangent line may not minimize the integral presented above. Considering $f(x)=x^{-4}$, given two points the midpoint tangent line is below the curve. Moving the line up by a little bit will make the linear approximation more fitted with the function and hence a better approximation. However that might still be a good place to start.

Comment: As I said, it's an approximation.  Probably a good one if, say, $x_1,x_2$ are large and fairly close.  It's a question of what you are looking for.  Here, it's not particularly hard to work out the gradient of your function, but in other cases that might be extremely unpleasant, in which case it would be good to have a fast, simple way to approximate the result.

Comment: You can substitute in your definitions of $f$ and $g$ and evaluate your integral in terms of $\alpha, \beta, x_1, x_2$. You then just have a function that you're trying to minimise wrt $\alpha$ and $\beta$.